# how to get record base on max date in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
device_id                   out_date                      name
1                       '2015-09-24 11:00:23'             a
4                       '2015-09-23 11:00:23'             x
5                       '2015-09-22 11:00:23'             b
2                       '2015-09-29 11:00:23'             v
3                       '2015-09-23 11:00:23'             v
1                       '2015-09-212 11:00:23'            t
4                       '2015-09-15 11:00:23'             m
5                      '2015-09-18 11:00:23'              b
2                       '2015-09-20 11:00:23'             a             
3                       '2015-09-2 11:00:23'              s
1                       '2015-09-5 11:00:23'              s
4                     '2015-09-7 11:00:23'                s
5                      '2015-09-8 11:00:23'               s
2                     '2015-09-9 11:00:23'                e
3                    '2015-09-4 10:00:23'                 e
1                    '2015-09-7 7:00:23'                  s
4                     '2015-09-21 10:00:23'               s 
5                    '2015-09-23 12:00:23'                w
2                    '2015-09-1 10:00:23'                 s
3                     '2015-09-23 7:00:23'                s
```

This is my table i want record whose date_max from device id like we have 5 device id so it will like 1 max(out_date)  and name ,2 max(out_date)  and name ,3 max(out_date)  and name .... please suggest me how to implement it because i am getting Error with group by

i want output like this

```
1       max(out_date)     name
2       max(out_date)     name
3        max(out_date)    name
4        max(out_date)    name  
5       max(out_date)      name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this one:

```
select a.id, maxoutdate,b.name from
(select id,max(outdate) as maxoutdate from
(select id,max(outdate),outdate from tbl_device_outdate GROUP BY outdate ORDER BY id) as a GROUP BY id) as a

left JOIN

(select * from tbl_device_outdate) as b
on a.id = b.id and a.maxoutdate = b.outdate
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
  device_id,
  MAX(out_date)
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  device_id
```

If the error remains, please post the error and your query.

Comment: but i want unique device  i want only 5 data group by device_id

Comment: This question has been asked literally thousands of times. It's been answered correctly hundreds of times. This ain't one of them.

Comment: Then define your question better @ResearchDevelopment. Remove both of the 'name'-s from the query.

Comment: u ignore name just tell me  only device_id and max_outdate

Comment: @Dennisvdh u got any solution please suggest me how to implement this